# Sorting a list of IComparables

Tags: c#, sorting, iterator

I have a `DateTime` class (my own, not `System.DateTime`) which implements the `IComparable` interface.

Here is a method that takes a `List<DateTime>` and sorts it:

```
private List<DateTime> SortDateTimes(List<DateTime> dateTimes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dateTimes.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dateTimes.Count; j++)
        {
            if (dateTimes[i] < dateTimes[j])
            {
                var temp = dateTimes[i];
                dateTimes[i] = dateTimes[j];
                dateTimes[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    return dateTimes;
}
```

I believe using `foreach` loops instead of `for` is suitable here, but having the following variable names drives me crazy. :D

```
foreach(var dateTime1 in dateTimes)
{
    foreach(var dateTime2 in datetimes)
    ...
```

What are your thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't have a 'reinventing the wheel tag'...: have you considered using [`List.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)? Here you have provided a something not far off a (comparatively poor, since it lacks a cutoff) [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), which will take `n^2` steps to sort your list, where `n` is the number of items in the list. An 'efficient' sorting algorithm (as `List.Sort` will use) will do the same job in `n log(n)` steps, which is big difference for a large `n`.

Comment: Hmm, as said above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868600/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-with-icomparable-and-icomparer

Comment: @VisualMelon so all I need to do is `dateTimes.Sort()`?

Comment: @Sipo yeah, I think so. (It's a bit of a weird method, because it looks at the type (in runtime) to work out if it can sort it, part of which involves checking if it is `IComparable`; there are ways to make it more 'concrete')

Comment: @VisualMelon - Thank you so much. I feel really silly. :P Could you please elaborate on those ways in an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure it would qualify as an answer (since it isn't really about your code)... just have a quick read of the [Remarks for `List<T>.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_2) which details how the `DefaultComparer<T>` is prepared. As long as you don't try to do anything silly with it, nothing will go wrong, and if you _do_ try to do something silly with it then it will tell you by throwing an exception.

Comment: Splitting hairs - I'd call the `DateTime` class something else - just about anything else.  Obviously two types can have the same name, but it's not worth even the moment of confusion caused by using the same name as such a common type.

Answer (score 2):

### Prologue

> *I have a `DateTime` class (my own, not `System.DateTime`)*

You could have just pasted the code for that class. Since you are asking a question about sorting, and your `DateTime` class implements `IComparable`, its content could have been pivotal for a proper review.

### Parodos

> *Here is a method that takes a `List<DateTime>` and sorts it:*

You have just told us your class implements `IComparable`, but you don't show us how you'd use its functionality. I would have expected to to see `dateTimes[i].CompareTo(dateTimes[j])` but instead we get `dateTimes[i] < dateTimes[j]`. This means you have created an operator overload on `<` and are not sharing this crucial code with us.

Furthermore, why would you roll out your own sorting algorithm if built-in functionality is available? As suggested in the comments by VisualMelon, you could just call `dateTimes.Sort();`

### Exodus

> *I believe using foreach loops instead of for is suitable here, but having the following variable names drives me crazy*

To get things even more confusing, you ask about a syntactic change to the algorithm rather than going about how to properly sort or how to correctly implement `IComparable`.

Finishing off, in the `for (dateTime1 in dateTimes)` approach, you cannot change `dateTimes[i] = dateTimes[j];` as it will `throw System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.` rendering your suggested approach unusable.

### Cliffhanger

As a challenge, I let you search how to prevent this exception.

Comment: You've got downvoted! I wonder why... and the quesiton lost its two upvotes... one was from me the the other one is gone too. This is so weird o_O I'm not sure... is this question off-topic or not... strage things happen today.

Comment: @t3chb0t Perhaps it's off-topic, it's definately a border-line one, but it wasn't deemed off-topic back then. My main goal here was to confront OP with their own code and phrasing to make them reflect their design.

Comment: It seems to be more of a criticism about how I wrote the question rather than an answer. I believe you should write all of this in a comment.

Comment: @Sipo, it is to some extend criticism on the question, but at the end I also review your proposed solution. Would you like me to withdraw this answer or is it fine for you?

Comment: No, it's fine, I just explained why I think you got downvoted.

Comment: Also, this question was asked 1.5 years ago, and it is hard for me to improve it because I do not remember the details.

Comment: We are going through old posts to kill us some zombies: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9291/follow-up-possible-solution-for-zombies-the-brainstorm/9297#9297.